# Surprising property of an infinitely continuing function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Why is it that for the function $f(x) = x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}$ the value of $f(\sqrt{2})=2$ as we add more exponents to that pattern

Comment: Does $20$ equal infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=f(x)$, then consider $x^y$, can you see why $y=x^y$?

Now if $y=2$ what will the value of $x$ be?

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence converges to a limit $L$, then we have $L=\sqrt2^L$, so $L^{1/L}=\sqrt{2}$.  By considering the function $x^{1/x}$ show that the only possible values of $L$ are $2$ and $4$.

Now show that the limit exists, by proving that the sequence is increasing and bounded above (by $2$.)  Together, these results prove $L=2$.